# python try except 0

Tags: python

I am reading some python code written a while ago, and found this:

```
try:
    # do some stuff
except 0:
    # exception handling stuff
```

And I'm just not sure what except 0 means? I do have my guesses: Supposed to catch nothing i.e. let the exception propagate or it could be some sort of switch to turn debugging mode on and off by removing the 0 which will then catch everything.

Can anyone lend some insight? a google search yielded nothing...

Thanks!

Some sample code (by request):

```
            try:
                if logErrors:
                    dbStuffer.setStatusToError(prop_id, obj)
                    db.commit()
            except 0:
                traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Are you sure it was't written `except:0`? (note the placement of the colon)

Comment: NPE I am positive, I am looking at the diff right now. But I would assume except:0 would be equivalent to except:pass   ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when running it?

Comment: Could you show us some actual example of usage. It's really hard to second-guess whoever wrote that code without seeing what it is that they actually wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, This is very useful for debugging purposes (Catching the type of exception)

In your example 0 acts as a placeholder to determine the type of exception.

```
>>> try:
...   x = 5/1 + 4*a/3
... except 0:
...   print 'error'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> try:
...   x = 5/0 + 4*a/3
... except 0:
...   print 'error'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

In the first case, the exception is `NameError` and `ZeroDivisionError` in the second.
the `0` acts as a placeholder for any type of exception being caught.

```
>>> try:
...   print 'error'
... except:
... 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> try:
...   x = 5/0 + 4*a/3
... except:
...   print 'error'
... 
error
```

Comment: That's just the same as not having the `try`-`except` statement at all. The `except 0:` isn't actually doing anything here.

Comment: a `raise` in the except block to re-raise the exception would do the samething would'nt it

Comment: It is saving you reformatting a (potentially long) block of code to do it, however (hence debugging reference I'm guessing).

Comment: I guess it is one more way of doing the same thing as `raise`.

Comment: From python docs, except is defined as: `("except" [expression [("as" | ",") target]] ":" suite)` - and 0 is a valid expression, so it would not fail. There are more explicit ways of raising exceptions though.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

"[...] the [except] clause matches the exception if the resulting object is “compatible” with the exception. An object is compatible with an exception if it is the class or a base class of the exception object, or a tuple containing an item compatible with the exception."

In effect the type of the expression is used to determine whether the except clauses matches the exception. As `0` is of an integer type, and exception of that type would match.

Since integers cannot be raised as exception, this is a disabled `except`class that will not catch anything.

Comment: you cannot raise integer exceptions in python. `TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not int` on 2.7.3

Comment: @AhmedAeonAxan You're right. I just tried it out. Answer has been editied.

Comment: I think at one point (in the distant past) you might have been able to `raise int,0` which I think would have triggered the code in the except clause.  Now that statement raises an exception at **runtime**, but not **parse-time**, so the code may have never been updated. [reference1](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/ref/raise.html) [reference2](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/ref/try.html)